# Intellij-idea reverse paste into string (aka copy from string)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor, copy-paste

In Intellij idea if you paste some text into a string literal (between double quotes) the java editor can automatically reformat the pasted text - ie to place necessary escaping characters for double quotes new lines etc.
I want to do reverse, ie when copying text from inside a string literal the editor to place the clean text in the clipboard without the escaping characters, double quotes and new lines separated by plus signs etc.

For example when a paste these XML lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a></a>
```

into a string literal in Intellij Java editor it becomes:

```
String str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
             "<a></a>"
```

I want when I copy from this string literal to have an option for storing the clean text in the clipboard as it was before pasting. Ie to have the original text back.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Place cursor at *value* of the string and followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> |  `Copy String Concatenation Text to the Clipboard`

Comment: Just make sure that cursor points to the value, and not the variable name.

Comment: need same usecase in html

Comment: Repeatedly coming here because of forgetting this handy tips!!

Comment: Does not seem to work in PHP files when using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. Works fine for Java files.