# How to get pure String value from SQL format in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, intellij-idea

```
    @Query(value = " with cte as (\n" +
            "    select id, 1 as quantity\n" +
            "    from product\n" +
            "    where id = :productId\n" +
            "    union all\n" +
            "    select distinct combo_id as id,\n" +
            "                    quantity\n" +
            "    from combo\n" +
            "    where product_id = :productId),\n" +
            "     result as (\n" +
            "         select o.product_id, o.quantity * c.quantity as 'quantity'\n" +
            "         from order_product o\n" +
            "                  inner join cte c\n" +
            "                             on o.product_id = c.id\n" +
            "     )\n" +
            "select sum(quantity)\n" +
            "from result", nativeQuery = true)
    Object method(@Param("productId") String productId);
```

I am using Spring Jpa to write the SQL query, the IntelliJ supports me to reformat SQL easy to read.
However, when I try to copy this SQL to run in the database, it has a lot of redundant characters I need to remove such as + " \n. How can I do for copying only the value of this query?

Comment: Why you have added the \n? It is not needed.

Comment: it is automatically formatted by IntelliJ,  \n means new line

Comment: @HoangPhan When you cut and paste your CTE + query into IntelliJ, IntelliJ added that formatting.  You need to remove it to get back to the original SQL code.  Printing the string is one easy way to do that.

Comment: Seems like you can take advantage of this IntelliJ feature:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31699115/intellij-idea-reverse-paste-into-string-aka-copy-from-string

Comment: thanks @VladDed, these are the things that I am finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the query string and invoke `Copy string concatenation text to the clipboard`.

Also if you are working on Java 15 or higher, consider converting the string concatenation to a Text Block. (IntelliJ IDEA has a "Text block can be used" inspection for that). Text blocks are easier to copy and paste and easier to read as well:

```java
    @Query(value = """
         with cte as (
            select id, 1 as quantity
            from product
            where id = :productId
            union all
            select distinct combo_id as id,
                            quantity
            from combo
            where product_id = :productId),
             result as (
                 select o.product_id, o.quantity * c.quantity as 'quantity'
                 from order_product o
                          inner join cte c
                                     on o.product_id = c.id
             )
        select sum(quantity)
        from result""", nativeQuery = true)
    Object method(@Param("productId") String productId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following:

1. Add a `public static void main()` method to your current class.
2. Cut and paste the query string as `String value = " with cte as ..."`
3. Add a `println()` in the `main()` method

Then run your `main()` method and you should be able to cut and paste that output into your SQL tool.

Comment: I already thought this way, however, it is better if there is a way that is supported by IntelliJ

Comment: If you are using Java 17 and higher, you can use the multi line syntax: `@Query(value = """easy-to-read-multiline-string-without-concatenation""")`